# What does "You are not allowed to perform this operation" mean here?

Tags: ios, xcode

In xcode preferences, Accounts -> Manage Certificates, I got a weird prompt at the bottom of the dialog.

[image]

It says "You are not allowed to perform this operation. Please check with one of your Team Admins"

I have just renewed my developer membership and I'm the only one in the "Team".

Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Have you tried logging out and back in in Xcode's account preferences?

Comment: Have you checked the developer portal and iTunes Connect to make sure there are no contracts for you to agree to? You sometimes get locked out of various things if you have something missing in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had same, just after joining the Developer Program.   Agreeing to an iTunes Connect terms of service didn't fix it, but turning on Two Factor Authentication did.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you an account holder?

You could check [the permission of the Apple Developer account here](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles)?

The only account holder could create a Developer ID certificates.

[image: /]